# Get information about the user google plus api by token

Tags: google-oauth, google-plus-signin

I use the application android and get a token when making a request:
`oauth2:server:client_id:xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com:api_scope:profile email openid`

After that I want to get information on this token on the web server.
I'm trying to use:
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=xxx

But I do not get to get the data, how can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

To get a real token, you need to correct the request for url:
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token

and pass parameters by the POST method:
`grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=xxxx&code={code}`

code - a token of the type previously obtained 4/xxxxx